# how to compare two data frames of different lengths without getting identically-labelled series error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes corresponding to my train and test data respectively. They both have a column called 'Location'. I want to see which values in the 'location' column are the same in both the train and test dataframes and which values are not.
So for example  given two df:

```
df_train:
i  loc
0  10  
1  11  
2  12  

df_test:
i  loc
0  10  
1  12  
2  13
3  17
```

I would need it to return that 10 and 12 are in both dataframes, and that 11, 13 and 17 are only in df_test.Below is what I have tried:

```
df_t["match_location"] = np.where(df_tst["location_remapped"] == df_t["location_remapped"], "True", "False")
```

However I run into this error as both df are different lengths:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-49-51941d90b84e> in <module>()
----> 1 df_t["match_location"] = np.where(df_tst["location_remapped"] == df_t["location_remapped"], "True", "False")

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/ops/common.py in new_method(self, other)
     67         other = item_from_zerodim(other)
     68 
---> 69         return method(self, other)
     70 
     71     return new_method

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/arraylike.py in __eq__(self, other)
     30     @unpack_zerodim_and_defer("__eq__")
     31     def __eq__(self, other):
---> 32         return self._cmp_method(other, operator.eq)
     33 
     34     @unpack_zerodim_and_defer("__ne__")

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/series.py in _cmp_method(self, other, op)
   5494 
   5495         if isinstance(other, Series) and not self._indexed_same(other):
-> 5496             raise ValueError("Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects")
   5497 
   5498         lvalues = self._values

ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

Does anyone have a way around this?

Comment: Do you need to verify only the values in the dataframe or also the position of each value (the index)?

Answer (score 2):

If no duplicates in `loc` columns use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with outer join and parameter `indicator`:

```
df = df_train.merge(df_test, on='loc', indicator='match_location', how='outer')
print (df)
   loc match_location
0   10           both
1   11      left_only
2   12           both
3   13     right_only
4   17     right_only
```

For boolean column compare by `both`:

```
df['match_location'] = df['match_location'].eq('both')
print (df)
   loc  match_location
0   10            True
1   11           False
2   12            True
3   13           False
4   17           False
```

If possible duplicates first remove them:

```
df = (df_train.drop_duplicates('loc')
             .merge(df_test.drop_duplicates('loc'), 
                    on='loc', 
                    indicator='match_location',
                    how='outer'))
```